# Is it possible to download file from FTP using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser, ftp

Suppose, I've a FTP URL (`ftp://xyz.org/file.zip`). If I type this in the browser manually, then hit enter, the browser will start to download the `file.zip` and would ask me save it on harddisk.

My question is: Is it possible to write a script in JavaScript, which when run should download the file with all these options (separately)?

- in a new window?
- in a new tab in the same window?
- without opening a new window or tab?

Comment: `window.location = 'ftp://xyz.org/file.zip';`

Comment: I don't see why not. Have you tried `window.open("ftp://....")` or `window.location = "ftp://..."` in various browsers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

new window or new tab is controlled by the user's preference, and you can't override that. But to open your URL in a new tab/window you would use

```
window.open('ftp://xyz.org/file.zip');
```

to request it without opening a new window just

```
window.location = 'ftp://xyz.org/file.zip';
```

Comment: If we use `window.open()`, can we give the size of window as well?

Comment: @Nawaz, you can but I don;t see the point at all as the user is just going to get a "download to..." dialog.

Answer (score 2):

At the most basic just make a link like this:

```
<a href="ftp://...." target="_blank">Download in new tab/window</a>
```

In JS just open a window with that url.