# Java applet replacement technologies

Tags: java, web-applications, ftp, applet, jnlp

I have a **WEB-application** which implements Java Applet technology. **Java applet** itself is opened from **WEB-app** and it is a FTP-client which semi-automatically(pre-configured IP, un, pw...) gets a file list from a FTP-server and user selects a file to transfer.

In Applet, the file is downloaded via **FTP** and then streamed through **HTTPS** to the **WEB-app**.

This functionality now needs a replacement as the Applet are no longer supported by majority of the browsers.

My own thought is that this function would be replace with **JNLP**. As **JNLP** cannot be embedded into "same session", the upload phase to *WEB-app* must be implemented differently.

I've been thinking that *WEB-app* would provide an one-time upload URL which would receive the file and then continue processing it.

What other possibilities I have and what would you recommend?

Comment: Your Question is unclear. Your use of the term "web application" is confusing as that usually means an interactive HTML page not a Java Applet. I cannot tell if your applet Is what you mean by "web-application" or if you mean two separate systems. Please simplify your Question to the minimum of details.

Comment: Modified the question a little, sure the Applet and WEB-app are separate systems.

Comment: *"My own thought is that this function would be replace with **JNLP**."* Think again. While the majority of browser manufacturers have already removed the Java Plug-In, it seems Oracle is set to deprecate both applets **and JNLP** in Java 9. Can't everything mentioned above be done using JavaScript?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks for the pointer for deprecation of JNLP. For what I have understood, the FTP client is quite tricky/non-doable with JavaScript (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946684/implementing-ftp-using-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want less to no code changes, go with JNLP, otherwise, refactor the view (if your using MVC) to use modern java web technologies such as Servlets, JSPs or JSF.

Comment: Agreed. Specifically for this app I would consider using the Java Servlet based [Vaadin Framework](https://vaadin.com/framework).

Comment: Problem is not in server side but in client side. Because of network limitations it is required that the FTP-connection would be made from the client side.