# Is avaliable that web browser ftp request(LIST, MDTM , DownLoad, etc...) using Blazor?

Tags: c#, ftp, blazor

I have made a winform application that program is ftpClient using FluentFtp.dll(c# library).

My question is "Could I make web ftpClient".

I don't know well blazor.net.

but I heard that tech is able to make frontend using c#.

I have tried my ftpClient code move to @code{} block.

```
private void GetListFTP()
{
    FluentFTP.FtpClient ftpClient = new FluentFTP.FtpClient("server host","server port(integer)","my id","my password");
    IList<FluentFTP.FtpListItem> items = ftpClient.GetListing("/", FluentFTP.FtpListOption.ForceList);
    IList<string> listStr = items.Select(itm => itm.Input).ToList();
}
```

but that code just work on Server(not Browser!).

If it isn't available, please recommand me javascript ftp libary.

Comment: ftpClient client handles ftp requests and responses. and with blazor you can present the responses on web page. it is possible but of course you need manually create the pages.

Comment: There's no `Blazor.Net` to begin with. Blazor runs on .NET Core so any FTP library that targets .NET Core or .NET Standard will work

Comment: i said ftpClient client handles ftp, not HttpClient

Comment: @LeiYang there's no `FtpClient` in .NET or .NET Core. The only built-in FTP support comes from FtpWebRequest. There was a third-party library with the unfortunate name `System.Net.Ftp`, which was renamed to `FluentFtp` in 2015

Comment: then change `ftpClient` to `FluentFtp.dll`. but i don't get your point. do you think it is impossible to create 'ftpclient in browser' with blazor?

Comment: @1min `that code just work on Server(not Browser!).` what code and what's the exact problem? Adding a DLL directly won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Blazor app is either Blazor WebAssembly or Blazor Server.

On WebAssembly [you can't do FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26946684/60761). As far as I know the only JS libraries are for Node.

On Blazor Server you can use any FTP client library available.

When your app runs in a Browser (regardless what framework) you need a Server to do your FTP, SMTP, Database access etc.