# Frontend Javascript Ftpclient

Tags: javascript, web, ftp, frontend, apache-ftpserver

So my Problem is about ftp in combination with javascript.

In my network i have a running ftpserver on port 21.
And i need a website, where the browser has access to the ftpserver via a ftpclient.
In the end it should be somithing like "filezilla" (ftpclient) running in the browser.
I thought it could work to built a client with javascript but couldnt find a library.
All i found was build for node.js, but thats backend and i need frontend.
Also i know that javascript has limited permission and isnt able to open ports.
Because of that my Ftpserver is configurated in passive mode, so the javascript code doesnt have to open ports.

Comment: You will need a backend for that probably

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implementing ftp using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946684/implementing-ftp-using-javascript)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.