# Is there a possibility to download text-content from ftp link programmatically?

Tags: javascript, html, ftp, embedded

I'm am on an embedded system which has an implemented webserver and a ftp-server.

Both servers are handled by a RTOS and I cannot change server-side code at the time.

I need to access and download text-files programmatically over the ftp-server from my website.

So far I am dynamically creating an ftp-link and open it inside a new window, which only shows me the text-content of the requested file.

Now I want to download this text content for serveral files I am about to open in a loop:

Open window - download textcontent - Close window
... Open Window ... and so on.

I cannot "inject" Javascript for the new window, to make it download it content if Im right?

I open the window with

```
window.open('ftp://username:passwort@myfilename.txt')
```

from a script running on my webpage.

Is there any possibility to access and download that text content as described?

At the time I do not have the possibility to access the textfiles other than ftp, since the webserver and ftpserver are not on the same filesystem and I can not change the code on the serverside.

Now I know this is kind of hacky... yet I need a workaround for now to access the textfiles.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using node you can try [node-ftp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftp)

Here's a quick example of how to use:

```
var Client = require('ftp');

var c = new Client();
c.on('ready', function() {
  c.get('foo.txt', function(err, stream) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(stream);
    stream.once('close', function() { c.end(); });
});
});
// connect to localhost:21 as anonymous
c.connect();
```

Comment: Can this be done on client-side? As I understand node.js is for server-side and unfortunately I cannot implement node.js on the server due to the RTOS. I mean that might be possible, but I have no clue IF thats the case, nor can I estimate the expenditure. Therefore I am trying to focus on the client side

Comment: it should work when you compile. There's also this option here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338444/is-it-possible-to-download-file-from-ftp-using-javascript?rq=1

Comment: I tried the solution with opening the ftp-link. But this is somehow browser-dependent how the links are handled. Most browsers just show me the text content in a new window/tab. I can right-click -> download them, but thats pretty much the thing i want to do automatically for serveral files without user-interaction. I am still confused with the node-ftp, bc I dont understand how to implement that inside my html/javascript files. As is said, i can only change the content and scripts on the client-side.